# Android Option Menu not working properly; what am I missing?

Tags: android, menu

I've been away from Java for some time --functional programming has been my muse-- and recently decided to jump back in with an android application. Things are going well. Javas syntax is mostly back in my brain, OO design principles are a little rusty, but I'm not afraid of re-factoring.

One problem I hit has been with the option menus in the platform. I load them from an XML file through a menu-inflator in my main activity (below), and I can see them! But, when I press them things get weird --but not like seeing your grandmother make-out with your best friend, much less weird.

For some reason, when I press the first button, I get the friendly `default` message in the code sample below, "That's not an option, moron!". And when I press the second, the message is "Adding One". I'm off by one somehow! But, but how!? but why!?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/add_single_id"
          android:title="@string/add_one" />
    <item android:id="@+id/add_multi_id"
          android:title="@string/add_multi" />
</menu>
```

... which is loaded by the menu inflator...

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

... and finally the listener for items selected.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ){
    switch( item.getItemId() ){
        case R.id.add_single_id:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Adding One", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            add_single();
            break;
        case R.id.add_multi_id:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Adding n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SelectMulti.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_LOADMULTI);
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "That's not an option, moron!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: booh, good one.. I believe your code is right and I tend to think it would be less surprising to see my grand mother making out with my best friend... ;)
And which value do you switch on if you print it in console?

Comment: and when you inflate the menu, can you list all item ids ?

Comment: can you clean your project and then run.

Comment: worked after a clean. I was thinking something along those lines when I was typing my question. I was really hoping eclipse was smarter then that, thanks --write a quick answer so I can check that sucker off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen to me many times when I am developing android on eclipse, and clean and rebuilding a project fixes it as it will recreate android Resource file and correctly map to your UI id's.

Comment: I just deleted the gen/ folder; is there anything else I might have to do?

Answer (score 1):

In your XML you have ID = add_one_id but in the code you use R.id.add_single_id